# Jekyll install on MAC OS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macos-mojave, jekyll-theme

I am trying to use Lanyon Theme for my static website hosted using Github pages. I have installed ruby on my MAC and changed the default path in .bash_profile. Gem and Jekyll are installed too. When I run jekyll -v I get a ***Loaderror***.

```
Library not loaded: Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: Users/<username>/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
Reason: image not found - Users/<username>/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
```

Steps followed until now:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin18]
gem -v
3.1.2
gem list
jekyll (4.1.1)
jekyll-sass-converter (2.1.0)
jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
which jekyll
/Users/<username>/gems/bin/jekyll
```

I see Jekyll is installed but why can't I use it. I am completely new to ruby and website building. Installing rvm etc is way too complicated for me that's why I used brew and changed my .bash_profile to include default PATH for gem and ruby. Can anyone please help me understand what am I missing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The error indicates an RVM installation is still active on your system. If you installed Ruby as a system executable you need to completely remove all RVM references from your shell before continuing. As it stands now it looks like you have a hodge podge setup, and that is a recipe for just a big mess.